# Play 2 and caching assets

Tags: scala, playframework

My application is supposed to download some same images from the internal service constantly and host them. I have implemented that by implementing an actor that is scheduled to retrieve the images. It places those under `/public/analytics` I have this default route set:

```
GET     /public/*file     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

But for some reason when I try to access an image via http://server/public/assets/image.png , I do not see the update. I think the problem is that it is cached. When I go inside my hosting, I see the updated image located in `/public/analytics` so it should be caching.

I have tried to add this to `Global`:

```
override def doFilter(action: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = EssentialAction { request =>
    import play.api.http.HeaderNames
    action.apply(request).map(_.withHeaders(
      HeaderNames.CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache",
      HeaderNames.PRAGMA -> "no-cache"
    ))
  }
```

But the result is still the same. Futhermore I see `no-cache` headers when I GET the image url. I saw a suggestion to generate new url each time, but I can't do that.

Any ideas what could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use the `Assets` controller, [you're getting caching, compression, etc support "out of the box"](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets#The-Assets-controller) - but you actually don't want it!

As you've discovered, it's a very convenient way to serve up content from other sources so perhaps the easiest way to solve this problem is to leave the caching in place, but specify a **very short [`max-age`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en#max-age) for everything**.

Looking at the [source of Assets](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/controllers/Assets.scala), it looks like if you specify an `assets.defaultCache`, you can do this; i.e. in your `application.conf`:

```
 assets.defaultCache="public, max-age=30"
```

Which means a standards-respecting browser will only retain an asset for 30 seconds before asking for a new one. You could make this match the period of your scheduled-retrieval actor for optimal efficiency.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work - I'm still getting the old image, even if I wait for 30 sec. I have tried to switch off the cache, see the code I've posted in the answer - and I am still keeping getting old image. Only when I implemented image retrieval over normal `Action`, I was able to make it react, but I am not sure this approach is any good

Comment: The weird thing that even after 3 hours I am still getting the old image. Is there any other thing except cache that can cause this?